# Set CSS for disabled button in DOJO

Tags: html, css, dom, dojo

Here is the image which says it all. I am trying to set the text color for the disabled button from #EEEEEE to black, but I cant seem to locate it via css. Any help will be greatly appriciated.

I added the line to color * to #EEEEEE, so I dont want to override that just change the color if the button is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Cascading. Something like this:

```
.dijitButtonDisabled .dijitButtonNode .dijitButtonText{
    color: #000;
}
```

With the assumption that `memberDetailsBtnBar` is root of the element tree shown in the image, the above rule will override your rule only if the button is in disabled state.

Comment: I found that changing my piece of code from color:#EEEEEE; to color:inherit; solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS

```
.dijitButtonDisabled .dijitButtonText{
    color: black;
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzrzoor5/1/

---

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom){
    // Create a button programmatically:
    var myButton = new Button({
        label: "Click me!",
        disabled: true,
        style: 'color: red'
    }, "progButtonNode").startup();
});
```